# Objective-C vs C++ for applied math algorithms

Tags: c++, objective-c, algorithm, cocoa

I'm an engineering student and I have a couple classes about different complex math problems and how to solve them exactly and numerically (approximation) using various algorithms. We have focused more on the actual math and the ideas of the solutions than implementations of them. The most of these that I have seen are written in C++. For some reason I don't really like C++ and I have fallen completely in love with Objective-C. (I own an apple computer)

Is it to much of a difference in efficiency between these to languages? I'm not planning on solving 40.000x40.000 navier-stokes equation systems, just some little/little-medium instances of practical problems. Most off the problems of interest are **P**-problems and for the **NP-Hard** good heuristics would be fine.

I am obligated to learn yet another programming language, or should I just go with Objective-C, a language that I'm very familiar with nowadays.

Comment: Objective-C using `Cocoa frameworks`

Comment: The performance differences when doing numerical computing will be minimal if your algorithms are correct.

Comment: This question belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Math you have another languages like:

- [R](http://www.r-project.org/) for statistic
- [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) for matrices and vectors
- [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) as CAS
- [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) for numeric computations
- The God of all mathematics computations [FORTRAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran)

Use right tool for right thing, and focus on idea not on algorithm (as you said).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll surely look into that. But I meant not only to do the calculations (for that I would just stick with Matlab) but to program applications that solves them.

Comment: Octave has C++ interface if you want that. SciPy is de facto Python library so you can build GUI over it. R has some GUI libs. Also all of them can pipe their output to your program.